# How should I restart my android application every time if the screen is locked?

Tags: android, task

I want to restart my Android application every time the user presses the lock button on my application, even if I have launched Gallery/Camera from my app; so that even the launched Gallery/Camera also gets cleared from my application task. Please suggest a way around for the same.

Comment: Why do you want to close your application when user presses lock button?

Comment: Override onStop() and onPause() method

Answer (score 0):

onStop() is being called everytime you click the lock button. So override the method to check if the screen is awake or not everytime onStop() is trigger then call your first Activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        if(!pm.isScreenOn()){

            Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this, YOUR_FIRST_ACTIVITY.class);
            PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this, 123456,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a service in background with notifiatoin and inside service detect screen is locked or not .
//createAndShowForegroundNotification will create a notification which is not //cancelable. then register the intent filter and don't forgetto unregister when //destroyed

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    createAndShowForegroundNotification(BackgroundSyncService.this, 9797);
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    mScreenReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

//this is the receiver that will be invoked when screen light is off inside service

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here

        } else{

              }
    }

}
```